# install mongodb extension for xampp on macos

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, php-mongodb

Ive been looking all night, and I havent been able to find a solution. 
Im trying to install the mongodb extension by running `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongodb`
but at the end I get this error

```
fatal error: 'unicode/usprep.h' file not found
#include <unicode/usprep.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.lo] 
Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: First google search result for me leads to `brew install icu4c` to include the library dependencies. I actually just searched for the include on Mac OS X, but there's actually an issue on  [PECL mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/883) as well.

Comment: I have already done this!

Comment: Sooo, it might just help people to respond to your question if you actually include the details of "what you have already done". No point forcing everyone to suggest things and then get the reply "I have already done this" is there. Add the detail to your question for "everything" you tried.

Comment: Have you able to solved it, i am facing same issue.

Comment: I have same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. I had `icu4c`, developer tools, everything I should have needed installed. It *should* have worked.. I was banging my head against this baffled at why it wouldn't compile.

**The issue was this:** It was trying to use the `icu4c` files located in the XAMPP directory (`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`). This is what shipped with XAMPP and NOT what you just installed (or had installed via `brew install icu4c`). It was using the wrong binaries to compile!

You can check where it's pulling from by doing: `which icuinfo`

It should be something like `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin/icuinfo` (path may vary, I am on MacOS Catalina and installed with homebrew) and NOT `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`.

Most of us have modified our `$PATH` to include the XAMPP bin directory and since icu4c is located at `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin` and `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin`, there is no knowledge of its existence. Those 2 specific `icu4c` paths are not in your systems path of locations to search for files in. So either A) it can't find it, or B) it finds the one in the XAMPP bin directory.

Since we basically have `icu4c` installed in 2 directories, we need to ensure the one we want is FIRST in our `$PATH` and BEFORE XAMPP!

#### SOLUTION

You should know how to modify your $PATH. I use iTerm and zsh (oh-my-zsh) just for reference.

I also added the `LDFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` values as was recommended after it successfully compiled.

Here is a snip from my `.zshrc` file:

```sh
# My cleaner way of organizing my paths
BIN=$HOME/bin
LOCAL_BIN=/usr/local/bin
HOMEBREW=/usr/local/sbin
COMPOSER=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
XAMPP=/Applications/XAMPP/bin
ICU4C_BIN=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin
ICU4C_SBIN=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin

export PATH=$HOMEBREW:$COMPOSER:$ICU4C_BIN:$ICU4C_SBIN:$XAMPP:$BIN:$LOCAL_BIN:$PATH

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Obviously you can ignore the `$HOMEBREW`, `$COMPOSER`, etc.. and apply as needed. I just separate them out to have a clean and easy to understand $PATH. Honestly, I really recommend organizing and separating your paths like I did above. It helps out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you first need to install icu4c:

```
$ brew install icu4c
$ brew link icu4c --force
```

Then modified your `$PATH` to include `icu4c`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"
```

And finally install `mongodb` driver for php:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```