# MongoDB PHP extension installation failed on macOS XAMPP

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, xampp, php-mongodb

I am trying to install the MongoDB PHP Extension in my MacBook Pro M1. I am facing the following error during installation.

The command I am using for installation

`sudo pecl install mongodb`

Error

```
/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.c:85:10: fatal error: 'unicode/usprep.h' file not found
#include <unicode/usprep.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Here is the output of `which php` and `which pecl` command

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin//php
```

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin//pecl
```

PHP version

```
PHP 8.1.4 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2022 03:15:01) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

What I tried (getting same error)

1. sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/pecl install mongodb
2. sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongodb
3. tried this solution [install mongodb extension for xampp on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272921/install-mongodb-extension-for-xampp-on-macos)
4. brew install icu4c

Mac version: `Ventura 13.3.1 (a)`

Comment: that error is compilation error, you just need to install the library which is missing in your case its **libicu** i guess

Comment: Is this similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75337336/6309)?

Comment: @Kazz I've installed that library still getting same error

Comment: then the added path link to wrong spot at github its like `icu/icu4c/source/common/unicode/usprep.h` in which case this `icu/icu4c/source/common/` should be added to path, but it is different on your system, try to locate the file, correct the path. also note that `export` command is temporary only for the shell which executed that command