# MongoDB extesion not installing using sudo pecl install mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, php-extension, pecl

I'm trying to install mongodb extenstion in MacOS (13.4.1) Chip (Apple M1 Pro) having Xampp installed with php verison PHP 7.4.1 using sudo `pecl install mongodb` but it's giving below error

```
fatal error: 'unicode/usprep.h' file not found
#include <unicode/usprep.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I have tried [install mongodb extension for xampp on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272921/install-mongodb-extension-for-xampp-on-macos) but it's also not working.

`which php` gives `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`
and `which pecl` gives `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/pecl`
and `which icuinfo` gives `/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin/icuinfo`

I have below paths exported in bash profile

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337336/fatal-error-unicode-usprep-h-file-not-found-when-installing-php-mongodb ?

Comment: Still same error appearing ```/Users/jitender/Downloads/mongodb-1.16.1/mongodb-1.16.1/src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.c:85:10: fatal error: 'unicode/usprep.h' file not found
#include <unicode/usprep.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.lo] Error 1``` @vectorialpx

Comment: Sounds like missing header files. You need to have them before you run `pecl install mongodb`. Check the requirements and provide them before running that command again. Header files are not binaries/executables, therefore changing $PATH will not change anything as it is for binaries only. It appears to me changing them was merely a brute-force attack to get it going, if that is your approach, you should try more and different things if you want to follow that path.